# Why doesn't my action filter get called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The code:

```
public class TheFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
    }
}

public class NotesController : BaseController
{
    [TheFilter]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditViewModel viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.Note.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        viewModel.Note.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
        var noteTable = StorageHelper.GetTable<Note>(viewModel.PageMeta.DataSourceID);
        noteTable.AddOrUpdate(viewModel.Note);
        return Home();
    }
}
```

When I debug on return Home() and step through then I bypass the action filter and go straight to the Home() method.

Am I declaring the action filter correctly?

Comment: I've recreated the scenario exactly as you have it above and my action filter is hit. I realize this information does nothing to solve your problem, but I thought you should know that your code is correct. Some other form of configuration may be causing the issue you're experiencing.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Should I declare the class with the name TheFilterAttribute or with the name TheFilter? I thought this may be a problem and tried that. However same result. It does not step into the OnActionExecuted

Comment: Just tried it without the 'Attribute' on the end of my action filter; it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: I did try that but no difference. Still trying to find a solution. I step line by line from the line before return Home() and it completely avoids the filter.

Comment: Can you try adding an override of `OnActionExecuting` and put a breakpoint in it? I'm curious if it gets hit.

Comment: Do you have anything modifying the global filters in your Global.asax?

Comment: Hello Nathan. I added another filter and now it seems to work. I will try removing that and test out if it works. I am rather confused but at least it's working.

Comment: Problem solved. What happens is that when return Home() is hit then it goes to the Home() action method. It executes this and then returns to finish off in the Edit method. I think I have my call wrong. What I want to do is go to the action method Home() as a redirect.

Comment: You should move your last comment to an answer so the question can be marked answered.

Comment: @NathanTaylor This exactly what I answered: "Maybe you don't reach the method directly but call Edit action from other action?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don't reach the method directly but call Edit action from other action?
put the filter on the controller and see what happens.

Comment: I am trying to apply a custom action filter on an action but it is not getting fired but when putting it above the controller it is can u help me out here?

Answer (score 31):

Make sure you're implementing

```
System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
```

and not

```
System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
```

They both have OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted Methods, so it can be a little deceiving.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue I was just missing the **override** keyword before the OnExecuting method. It started working after adding override keyword.

Answer (score -3):

Use the Onexecuting not onExecuted

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```